# Определение местоположение курсором на карте

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, mongoose, map

Реализую механизм нанесение пользователем маркера на карту по клику. Мне необходимо извлечь данные широты и долготы это маркера, вывожу latLng - пусто, latit- выводит значение. В чем может быть ошибка? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полученные значения широты и долготы необходимо сохранить в БД в схему:

```
var sightsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    sight:{
        longit: Number,
        latit: Number
    },
    oversight: {...}
});
```

Добавление метки на карту по клику:

```
 var map2;
    function initMap() {
        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locationSight'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: {lat: 48, lng: 43}
        });
        map2.addListener('click', function (e) {

            placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map2);
        });
    }
    function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map2) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map2
        });
        map2.panTo(latLng);

        var latit = latLng.lat();
        var longit = latLng.lng();
        console.log('latit', latit);
        console.log('latLng', latLng);
        document.querySelector('.inputLat').value = latit;
        document.querySelector('.inputLng').value = longit;
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, о какой карте идет речь?

Comment: @анатолийшевелев, googleMap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792655/add-marker-to-google-map-on-click

Comment: почему в консоль выводится `latLng` а не `longit` ?